# Does modifying gcp projects in terraform modifies resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

So i have created a project with terraform under an organization.

```
 resource "google_project" "my_project" { 
  name       = "My Project"
  project_id = "your-project-id"
  org_id     = "1234567"
      }
```

I have also created resource inside the project now i want to modify the project, i want to add "auto_create_network = false" does it effect the resources that are not using default vpc inside the project. As i don't want this change to effect the services(not using default vpc) that are running inside gcp. Any suggestion/advice is appreciated.

Comment: What does `terraform plan` indicate?

Comment: It is indicating  "0 add 1 change 0 destroy" but this statefile is for project only we have different statefile for services.